# How can I create a zoomable page like maps with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a page like this with flutter but I couldn't find right widgets. Sample app is below.
[Sample page fif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkK2c.gif)

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/25164/files might help

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: see [MatrixGestureDetector](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/matrix_gesture_detector)

Comment: I tryed MatrixGestureDetector. I ran all examples. I think that's what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what i needed thanks to pskink
[Matrix Gesture Detector](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/matrix_gesture_detector)