# Flutter: How to make a rotatable coordinate system by gesture like maps in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, flutter, ubuntu, gesture

I want to create a page with a rotatable coordinate GestureDetector system run on Ubuntu and Android like this [Video](https://youtu.be/9lDE5JlAyX0)

This is my code use InteractiveViewer, CustomPainter and GestureDetector:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('My App')),
            body: InteractiveViewer(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                height: double.maxFinite,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: CustomPaint(
                      painter: MapPainter(
                    context: context,
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            )));
  }
}

class MapPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final BuildContext context;
  final double resolution = 0.05;

  MapPainter({required this.context});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.save();
    {
      drawGrid(canvas);
    }
    canvas.restore();
  }

  void drawGrid(Canvas canvas) {
    int numOfGrid = 50;
    if (resolution == 0) return;
    for (var i = -20; i <= numOfGrid; i++) {
      canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(i / resolution, -numOfGrid / resolution),
        Offset(i / resolution, numOfGrid / resolution),
        Paint()..color = Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
      );
      canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(-numOfGrid / resolution, i / resolution),
        Offset(numOfGrid / resolution, i / resolution),
        Paint()..color = Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MapPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I tried matrix_gexture_detector like this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827768/8181863) but the rotation function only works for Android, I don't know how to rotate in Ubuntu.
[matrix_gesture_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector)